# arp poisoning and mitm protection

Tags: arp, arp-poisoning

I'm trying to understand mitm by arp poisoning. To do so I'm practicing on the network I manage:

- attacker : IPA
- victim : IPC
- gateway : IPG

I use nighthawk, and kali linux (via virtual box).

I can poison the victim by using arpspoof under kali linux. `arp -a` on victim confirms the MAC replacement for the gateway.

but I never can setup a mitm attack because:

- my gateway (IPG) is a TG670s
- when I start poisoning it, the victim becomes to receive arp message: `IPG ask who is IPC`
- that kills my poisoning on IPC

I think this is a defense mechanism of the gateway, but I can't find article on this mechanism (send a query on unsolicited answer).

Is my guess correct ? Or do I miss something ?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5227#section-2.4

Comment: @XavierLucas ty, but not all devices implements this, isn't it ?